# Issue with building 32 bit Qt 5.2.1 applications in 64 bit operating system (centos with gcc 4.8.2)

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

During building Qt 5.2.1 applications (32 bit) in CentOS (64 bit with gcc 4.8.2), I got following error:

```
main.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note that I have inserted following statement in the qt project file (Pro file):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-m32
```

Comment: You're most probably mixing 32-bit and 64-bit objects/libraries.

Comment: Is your Qt also built 32-bit? I'd start with that.

Comment: Yes, It has built 32-bit. I have create a simple gui app and it gives the error yet!

Comment: I have used prebuilt qt installer (.run)

Comment: What about `QMAKE_LDFLAGS`? Could you try adding `-m32` there too?

Comment: I've just tried it and it's not working yet. Another thing: the gcc is 4.8.2 and the qt is built with 4.8.1

Comment: Do you have any idea?!

Comment: Use -spec linux-g++-32 instead of messing with cxx flags manually

Comment: How can i use it with make?

Comment: @Mosi You need to give the spec to `qmake`, not `make`: `qmake -spec linux-g++-32`. This should be handled automatically if you build using Qt Creator, you'll be able to select whether you use a 32 or a 64 bit kit.

Comment: @Mosi, can you provide a simple main function and a project file reproducing this issue?

Comment: Ok, QMAKE_LDFLAGS=-m32 solved my problem. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QMAKE_LDFLAGS=-m32 solved my problem. Thank you guys